# How to Use same logfile but Change its Location while ongoing ddrescue process?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, hard-drive, ddrescue

I am recovering the data from a damaging external WD hardrive 1TB to another new WD 1TB hardrive using the command.

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r 3 /dev/sdc '/media/jordan/Empty My Passport/ddrestored/drive.img' '/media/jordan/Empty My Passport/ddrestored/drive.log'
```

See I am using same location for both image file and log file.
I am in middle of ddrescue operation.

Already rescued size is more than 40gb.
errsize is 959GB.

I want to change the log file location and then resume from wherever I left beacuse Both the destination and source drive are of same size.Exact Same size,Same company, So logfile will take few bytes of space and will result to failure of ddrescue operation at the end.

Please tell me How to do this?

Should I interupt using "ctrl+c" then "copy and paste" the log file to another drive and
then change the command of ddrescue, something like this:-

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r 3 /dev/sdc '/media/jordan/Empty My Passport/ddrestored/drive.img' 'new_log_file_destination'
```

???

Comment: You cannot. You would have to make `ddrescue` redo its `open` system call.

Comment: Sorry but I so.I already interupted and cut and paste the logfile to another location.I resumed by changing the command.It is working from where it left.